# Unable to get WAF to run

Tags: python, wsh, waf

I am trying to build the Monotooth library on Ubuntu and there is a native component which needs to be compiled.  The distro from github has a wscript file and requires WAF to build.  However, whenever I try to execute waf configure I get:

```
Checking for program gcc                 : ok /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for program cpp                 : ok /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : ok /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : ok /usr/bin/ranlib
 error: No such method 'create_library_configurator'
```

I don't know python and I'm not sure what this is actually telling me.  Am I missing a library (module) or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I needed to use a version of waf from http://waf.googlecode.com/files/waf-1.3.2.tar.bz2

I had version 1.5.9 which must have deprecated the create_library_configurator method.

Comment: this version type of issue is why war documents say that waf itself should be copied into the projects version control